# Hello World , Have Paspberry Pi and A Sim7000A Board GSM need Help

Tags: pi-4, pi-zero

Hello I have a raspberry pi 4 and was given a SIM7000A Board GSM.

I believe I have it wired correct.

Any one know how to hook this up and be able to use it ... I am real new to this and would like as much guidance to use it as possible.

any one hook one of these up?

can you let me know how you got it working Please!

like to use with my pi-zero as well.

Comment: have you looked for tutorials?

Comment: *I believe I have it wired correct.* - maybe not, we can't tell. Also how are you trying to "use" it, i.e. some code?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/rpi3b-python-controlling-multiple-sim800-sim900-sim7600-modules

Comment: I would also ask - what do you aim to do with it and is your sim set up for data?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if I hook up something that doesn't "just work" (and the blue smoke doesn't burst forth), I have to step back and break things into smaller steps. Does each part in isolation work?

1. can you get the board to work with another computer? The hardware manufacturer will have some sort of documentation to attach it to something, like maybe a PC. So, hook it up to a PC and learn how it acts (blinkie lights, data sent via usb, etc.).
2. is your Raspberry Pi happy? does it boot and work normally w/o GSM attached.

The process of getting this far will teach you things you'll find helpful going forward.

3. from the shell start doing USB commands. e.g. lsblk, dmesg with the GSM unhooked and then after you plug it in. Do not fear plugging-in/unplugging GSM usually. I've found that when I'm lost, looking at the change of lsblk output (when I unplug, then plug in) can tell me something helpful.
4. start haunting the board's website/blog/git-repos and duplicate what you find there. They know best how to the board works. They know how they verify their product is working, and they should be willing to share troubleshooting hints with you. Remember, their motivation is to sell a working product, not solve your problem, don't be too demanding.

Good luck. (and work to improve your luck)