# GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT issue

Tags: pi-4, gps, hat

I have a HAT from Waveshare which i am using only for GPS.
The GPS output from minicom looks like this, it was in use for more than 4 hours straight, but nothing changed.
How do I troubleshoot this?

```
AT+CGNSINF
+CGNSINF: 1,0,19800106002233.000,,,,0.00,0.0,0,,,,,,0,0,0,,,,                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                 
OK
```

Comment: is the issue that there is no GPS signal? I mean, that the HAT isn't able to detect any GPS signal, because I'm sure the many GPS satellites are still there :p

Comment: sim8xx/9xx/76xx? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/rpi3b-python-controlling-multiple-sim800-sim900-sim7600-modules/114038#114038

Comment: Which HAT ? Waveshare have several. And as @JaromandaX say, can the GPS module see a clear sky and some models need a antenna, is it connected?

Comment: Your problem seems general, not specific to Waveshare hat. These general references might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/rpi-neo-6m-neo-8m-gps-module-setup-fix-update-problems/113601#113601

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the module indoors or outdoors? If you are trying it indoors, please take the module outdoors. Keep the module in a location with a clear view of the sky. GPS modules usually require a direct line of sight to the sky to receive signals from satellites.

Comment: It was outside the window for more than 4 hours, clear view to the sky.

Comment: I think you have to check if the power supply is adequate. If you find no problem at your side, I think you should contact waveshare as soon as possible. There maybe a manufacturing error. If the HAT is still within the warranty period, you may get a replacement. By the way, if you wish to make a GPS/GNSS HAT by yourself, you can see here: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/GNSS_HAT_for_Raspberry_PI_69274fdf.html