# SIM800 shield as Internet provider

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, internet, gsm

I've been using for a while a Huawei USB dongle as an Internet provider for my Raspberry Pi, which I have connected to my solar panels system at my country house (which doesn't have an accessible Internet connection, just mobile data); and gives me updates all the time through EmonCMS and Home Assistant, which I have installed on another Raspberry Pi at home. The issue is that the USB dongle is a bit bulky, and doesn't fit very well in [the box](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32867639159.html) that I'm using for the Pi. So after a bit of research (not enough, definitely), I finally decided on buying one of those SIM800C shield modules which are [sold in AliExpress](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4001235699045.html) and are really cheap.
The issue is that I thought that there were a lot of good tutorials on how to use the module, but I haven't figured out yet how to use, neither with AT commands nor as the final use I want (as an Internet card).

If any of you could take my a hand I'll be really pleased. Greetings.

Comment: Check out [How to connect SIM800 GSM ADD-ON to RaspberryPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55382/how-to-connect-sim800-gsm-add-on-to-raspberrypi-3). If you don't want to pay for the add-on board, you'll have to do the wiring yourself.

Comment: Ok, will try it out @DmitryGrigoryev, wiring won't be an issue, thank you very much.